# longtable in RMarkdown pdf: No pagebreak for only one line

Tags: r-markdown, kable, longtable

I am creating serial reportings.

I have a long table, created with `kable`. In some reports the pagebreak in the table unfortunately happens in a way that only one row of the table ends up on the next page. Can I prevent this? E.g. saying, that on each page there needs to be at least 2 rows?

Example:

````
---
title: "Example_long_table"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
   \usepackage{longtable}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
```


```{r longtable, echo=FALSE}
  knitr::kable(cars[1:40,],
               caption = "long table",
               booktabs = T,
               longtable = T)%>%
        kable_styling(latex_options = c("HOLD_position", "repeat_header"))
```
````

I tried looking in the tex file, but it looks like I need to change something in the `kable` in order for this to work.